# raise Warning in QWeb

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I created a **QWeb** report in that I'm calling a method in that I put a condition if that condition not **True** then it will raise a **Warning**, but it's show its **own warning**.

for example my code like

```
def to_data(self,order_id)
    sale_order_id = self.env['sale.order'].browse(order_id)
    if not sale_order_id.is_demo_order:
         raise Warning(_("Warning"))
```

I imported required packages.
The warning should be show like "Warning" but actual its show like,

```
Error to render compiling AST
UserError: (u'Warning')
Template: my_module.report_sale_order_label
Path: /templates/t/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/img
Node: <img style="width:100%;height:75%;align='center'" t-attf-src="data:image/png;base64, #{order.to_data(order.id)}" data-oe-id="784" data-oe-model="ir.ui.view" data-oe-field="arch" data-oe-xpath="/t[1]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody[1]/tr[4]/td[1]/img[1]"/>
```

I'm calling that to_data() method from `<img>` tag.
There is any way to generate warning from **QWeb**?

Answer (score 0):

Try `confirm` in xml.
Example:

```
  <button name="cancel_voucher" string="Cancel Receipt" type="object" states="posted" confirm="Are you sure you want to cancel this receipt?"/>
```